# Mapbox adding a long object that lines up with the road

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Is it possible to draw a line that curves around the road when only given Geo point and a length?

Using Mapbox GL.

example will be I have a train I want to draw on the rail.

train object will be

```
{ gps: {lat:xxxxx, long:xxxx }, length: 5}
```

I would like it to draw on the map so that it curves around the rail as a map layer

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Are you using a map server or is this all on the front end?

Comment: This question might have more luck on https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Christian4423 added example

Comment: You may want to download some rails data. I would check if your state has a shapefile you can download for free. For example, I am in Michigan I can get free data at https://gis-michigan.opendata.arcgis.com/. You will want your application to select a railroad line. Once selected, you can place a point anywhere on that line. You can assign a symbol to that point... which could be an image of a train.

Comment: Here is an example of the railroad data in Michigan. https://gis-michigan.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/railroads-v17a/explore?location=44.248650%2C-86.321100%2C7.56

Comment: @Christian4423 we already got rail data and layered on the map. So you saying next step is create train symbols and place them on the line, then it will curve around the rail?

Comment: Yeah. I am not familiar with Mapbox so much. Is this what you are looking for? https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html (OpenLayers)

Comment: @Christian4423 not really, there is a https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/polyline/route.json route data there which i wont have. I only get a point, length and direction. I dont even get 2 points to use as a route